# what is the difference between "ssh user@ip" and "ssh ip user"?

Tags: linux, ssh

I am facing problem with one of the above.

Only `ssh user@ip` works not the other way round. And I am getting the following error when I run `ssh ip root`

```
sh: root: not found
```

Because of this I GUESS one of the application which uses the problematic syntax is not able to login.

Comment: you can use either `ssh user@ip command` or `ssh -l user ip command`/ command need to be found on ip within user's $PATH.

Comment: Is there a page on the internet that says `ssh ip user` is a valid sintax? Not even dropbear(altenative micro ssh client) uses this sintax - http://linux.die.net/man/1/dbclient

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ssh user@ip` is correct syntax. The other logs in to the host `ip` as you and tries to run a command called `root`.

Please update your question with an explanation of what are you actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

As said by others `ssh user@ip` is the correct sintax. If you use `ssh ip user`, the "user" part is actually a command to be executed on the remote host.

When you suppress the `user@` part from the correct sintax, you are actually passing your local user to the remote host. If you don't have a user with the same name, or it is a disabled user on the remote host you will get an error.

What the error message is trying to say to you(`sh: root: not found`) is that there is no root command on the remote host.

**ssh synopsis**

```
ssh [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] 
  [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] 
  [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file] [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
  [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] 
  [-Q cipher | cipher-auth | mac | kex | key | protocol-version] 
  [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] 
  [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname [command]
```

**Related stuff**

- [ssh(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/slogin.1?query=ssh&sec=1) manpage

Answer (score 1):

If you check the manual page of `ssh` by `man ssh`, you'll find the related syntax

```
ssh [...] [-l login_name] [...] [user@]hostname [command]
```

So when it parse your command, it will treat the first argument without flags to be the hostname, and what comes after it as a command passing to the remote for execution.

Come back to your case. If you put your name after the hostname, then it will be treated as a command. And that's why it prompt you that error message. Because command `root` cannot be found in remote host.